# how to read a value from an array

Tags: arrays, delphi, static, record

I have an array which I need to read the first value from the array and then read the following values once used.:

```
type
  TMyCardRecord = record
  CardSet:integer;
  CardValue:integer;
  CardPicture:TBitmap;
  end;
Var
    PlayerCards : array[1..12] of TMyCardRecord;

procedure TForm2.StartClick(Sender: TObject);   //Start New Game Button
var
duplicate : boolean;
pc,p,i : integer;
y, filename : String;

begin
FileName:=('S1.bmp');  ;

  for i := 1 to 12 do
    begin
y := (playercards[i]+filename);
image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(y);
end;
```

When i try to add `playercards[i]+filename` it says incompatible types: `string` and `TMyCardRecord`.

How can i make it so that the value `playercards[i]` is compatible? the `playercards` array contains values which are based on their assigned image. I need the value to be converted to an `integer` to work I think.

Comment: You already have a file name in "filename", what do you want to prepend to it, directory?

Comment: Why are you trying to add `filename` to the array element?

Comment: Your question can be more clear by explaining how your actual file names look like and what your array elements actually hold.

Comment: filename is the same every time its just the number in front that changes to select a different value  e.g 1S1.bmp  or  5S1.bmp.

Comment: It's not your record that holds 1 or 5, it's a field of the record. Use that, and convert it to string. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42627685/edit) your question to include relevant information.

Comment: Well worth learning how to interpret compiler error messages like this. No need to ask the question really, if only you could read and comprehend the error.

Answer (score 4):

`playercards[i]` is an instance of `TMyCardRecord`.
You are trying to add a a string to this instance of `TMyCardRecord`. This addition of a string and a custom type is not defined.
That is what "incompatible types" means - Delphi doesn't have a clue how it can add a string and a record, because they're entirely different things, and addition between them is not defined.

What you apparently want, is a file name based upon the specific card.
You need to retrieve the values that you want in the filename - probably the value of the card and the suit (`CardValue` and `CardSet`). Then you need to convert these to strings. You can use the `IntToStr` command for this.
So: `IntToStr(playercards[i].CardValue)` and `IntToStr(playercards[i].CardSet)`.

The easiest way to go about this, is to create a function that takes these values and turns them into a string.
Then you add that string to `filename`.